# Semicolon error after 'limits'?

Tags: semicolons, dependent-clause

The original sentence is as follows:

> Though Ramez Naam does not entirely deny the possibility of a self-reliant AI in his quote like Pinker does in this article, the words from Naam’s quote show that AI has its limits; therefore, giving Pinker some support to his argument.

My professor circled the semicolon after 'limits' and I am unsure if there is an error because I used a semicolon incorrectly or if the error has to do with 'limits'. The error could also be that I have a dependent clause after 'therefore' but I think if that were the case my professor would not have circled my semicolon.

Comment: It looks like you are trying to use _therefore_ as a conjunctive adverb, but you do not have a complete clause after. I would change it for a simple comma, and remove the comma after. That, or rephrase the last bit so that it is an independent clause.

Comment: The semicolon is a problem because it logically separates the final eight words of the sentence from everything that went before—and those eight words can't stand on their own. But there are problems here that go beyond the question of which punctuation mark, if any, should go before _therefore_. The sentence is overstuffed, a fault that I would address by splitting it in two: "Ramez Naam does not entirely deny the possibility of a self-reliant AI, as Pinker does in this article. Nonetheless, Naam’s statement indicates that AI has its limits, which offers some support to Pinker's argument."

Comment: I am surprised he did not mark the use of "_like_ Pinker does".

Answer (score 3):

Semi-colons are used (among other reasons) as a replacement for the full stop  (period) when the two independent clauses (phrase with a subject + predicate) are related in thought and given equal merit. If you were to replace that semi-colon with a period, then "therefore..." would not be a grammatically correct sentence as it does not have both a subject and predicate. Therefore, that semi-colon is incorrect.